# why does jquery $(window).load() only work on page reload and not on first visit in ie8?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

When I load my page in ie8 my $(window).load  function does not fire.  If I then refresh the page it fires.

I am experiencing this issue only in ie8.

My jquery version is 1.10.2 (as I understand it ie8 is still supported in jquery 1, support for older ie browsers has only been dropped in jquery 2)

To be clear I am loading the content inside of a standard .load function syntax:

```
$(window).load(function(){

});
```

Jquery is called inside the  tag and the load function is called inside the body.

In an attempt to debug this I tried adding a quick script just inside the body tag to check if jquery is loading.

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
    alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
}else{
    alert("jQuery library is not found!");
}
```

Not only does the "jquery library is loaded!" alert fire correctly both when the page first loads and after each refresh, but now the .load function fires correctly.

When I remove this test again the problem comes back.

I tried older jquery versions (1.9.1 and 1.8.3) with the same result.

Finally I tried using:

```
$(function () {

});
```

This fires 3/4 of the time, and  I know this is not exactly the same as .load (it fires before .load), so I am assuming my issue has something to do with timing but I have run out of ideas.

Can anyone give me any suggestions to get this working

Comment: never debug with `alert`, it skews the results. If alert is causing it to magically work, that means you have something asynchronous running that is required to be done before the rest of your code works, and the alert is giving it time to finish.

Comment: are you sure you have to use load() and not ready()? it sounds like it

Comment: @Kevin B .  Yes I know using alert is a bit sloppy and the fact that it stopped working again when I removed it lead me to the idea that it is a timing issue. Using setTimeout inside of $(function() { to delay the code from firing for an extra second once again fixed the issue, which further supports your suggestion.

Comment: Can we see the code in the context of the page? Where is it being called?

Comment: OK, I founded @KevinB, you are right. I am using a jquery plugin called respond.js to fix some responsive css queries for ie8 and it appears to be this that is causing the problem.

Comment: Well, i say never debug with alert, but i guess without it would have taken longer to realize that this was a race condition.

Comment: @KevinB . Very true, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. As your helpful tip was a comment and not an answer I have upvoted the comment.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is going to sound insane — although we are dealing with legacy IE, so bear with me — but have you tried using the `new` keyword when declaring your function?

```
$(window).load(new Function(){
});
```

Comment: This would fire the function *immediately* and set the load handler to the "object" created by the function.  I'm assuming this is *not* what he wants to do.